# dd command without verbose mode

Tags: linux, dd

I don't need dd command verbose, my idea is to write it to a file, like this:

```
sed -n 1,200000p fileinfo | while read line  
do   
    # $path is the directory path
    dd  if=file1 of="$path/file2"  bs=1000000  &>trash-file
done
```

But it takes a time. Is there any way to do this faster?

Comment: What is the meaning of **more quickly?** Can you make it explicit?

Comment: @student for example if there exist a switch to set that stopes verbose. the time will decreas

Comment: What are you talking about? dd isn't verbose. It prints, like, a 3-line summary of what it did at the very end.

Comment: `bs=10`?  You're using `dd` to copy a file with 10-byte blocks?  That could certainly make it take a good long time.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It was an example, I'll fix it

Comment: @AndrewMedico Its not my full script I have this command in a for command that runs several time

Comment: Have a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11262/15241 to see if dd still does something.

Comment: @vida1 I can't answer it but can do a +1 to keep this question alive.